# How to see GRANTS for all users on a concrete DATABASE? MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I want to see the GRANTS for all the users on a concrete DATABASE.

I use

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

but it shows the GRANTS for all the databases (I suppose).

I want to see, for example, if I apply:

```
GRANT ALL ON Movies TO 'jNavarro';
```

I want to see how the GRANTS are changed to Y on the Movies Database, because If i apply the SELECT shown before the Grants for jNavarro doesn't change.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are an admin then running this will get you what you want

```
select user from mysql.db where db='DB_NAME';
```